# PHP Class Properties change after assigned to variable

Tags: php, class, variables, properties

Take this example. I never noticed behaviour like this:

```
class foo
{
    public $foo = 0;

    public function addFoo()
    {
        $this->foo = $this->foo + 1;

        return $this;
    }
}

$bar = new foo;

$a = $bar;
$b = $bar->addFoo();
$c = $bar->addFoo();
```

I assumed that after the script is completed:

> $a->foo is: 0
>
> $b->foo is: 1
>
> $c->foo is: 2

But that's NOT the case. I get:

> $a->foo is: 2
>
> $b->foo is: 2
>
> $c->foo is: 2

I don't understand, why $a->foo is 2. It's no pointer and is never altered.

Maybe someone can explain or show me a link to PHP's documentation, where this is covered.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are always passed "by reference"*. If you assign an object to another variable or return it from a function, **you are not creating a copy of the object.** To explicitly *copy* an object, you need to `clone` it.

<sub>* Not in the `&` meaning of "reference" though. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php</sub>

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is this

```
$bar = new foo();

$a = $bar;

$b = $bar->addFoo();
$c = $bar->addFoo();
echo $a->foo;
echo  $b->foo;
echo  $c->foo;

o/p = 2, 2, 2
```

This will always return 2 because it is returning the last value of $foo(i.e $this) variable of class after all the adds operation have been done.

Try this to get what you want

```
$bar = new foo();

$a = $bar;
echo $a->foo;

$b = $bar->addFoo();
echo  $b->foo;

$c = $bar->addFoo();
echo  $c->foo;

 o/p = 0, 1, 2
```

This will give you 0, 1, 2 output as it will print value of $foo after each add operation.

Hence to summarize your addFoo() function is returning the class object and because of that in previous case the class object was holding the value of $foo and when you again call that addFoo() it adds + 1 to the $foo variable. Hence all the variables where holding the same object of the class.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I thought by mistake that $a will keep the init. value.

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object. $this is a reference to the calling object. In your case When you are returning $this you are returning a reference to the object $bar
and $a, $b and $c holds copy of identifier $bar.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php